# Pandas DataFrame columns separating

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

I have a large DataFrame, in which there is only one column with all the values. I need to separate the data into more columns. After a lot of trial and error, I gave up and sought to your help.

the head of the DataFrame looks like this:
the rows are a Series object. not values

```
                                                        column1
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------
    MultiIndex1  | 1.00   2.00   3.00   4.00   5.00   6.00   7.00
                 | 1.00   2.00   3.00   4.00   5.00   6.00   7.00
                 | 1.00   2.00   3.00   4.00   5.00   6.00   7.00
                 | 1.00   2.00   3.00   4.00   5.00   6.00   7.00
                 | 1.00   2.00   3.00   4.00   5.00   6.00   7.00
                 | 1.00   2.00   3.00   4.00   5.00   6.00   7.00
```

my desired output should look like this:

```
                 column1|column2|column3|column4|column5|column6|column7
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------
    MultiIndex1  | 1.00 |  2.00 |  3.00 |  4.00 |  5.00 |  6.00 |  7.00
                 | 1.00 |  2.00 |  3.00 |  4.00 |  5.00 |  6.00 |  7.00
                 | 1.00 |  2.00 |  3.00 |  4.00 |  5.00 |  6.00 |  7.00
                 | 1.00 |  2.00 |  3.00 |  4.00 |  5.00 |  6.00 |  7.00
                 | 1.00 |  2.00 |  3.00 |  4.00 |  5.00 |  6.00 |  7.00
                 | 1.00 |  2.00 |  3.00 |  4.00 |  5.00 |  6.00 |  7.00
```

i've tried to:
df.columns = ['col1','col2','col3','col4','col5'...]

i've tried turning it into a series and back to a df.

tried applying .str.split functions.

lots of slicing and concat, but no success.

help would be much appreciated.
Thanks!

here is the first few lines of my dataset, as an example:

the date and AALR3 are the Row MultiIndex

2019-01-02;AALR3                                             ;0000000020; 000000000013.300000;000000000000000100;10:00:04.961;1;2019-01-02;000086597137782;000000000310091;2;2019-01-02;000086597142909;000000000310092;1;0;00000072;00000174
2019-01-02;AALR3                                             ;0000000010; 000000000013.310000;000000000000003000;10:00:04.961;1;2019-01-02;000086597135827;000000000310088;2;2019-01-02;000086597142909;000000000310089;1;0;00000120;00000174
2019-01-02;AALR3                                             ;0000000050; 000000000013.390000;000000000000000200;10:11:40.214;1;2019-01-02;000086597182855;000000000400273;1;2019-01-02;000086597151579;000000000400274;2;0;00000058;00000008
2019-01-02;AALR3                                             ;0000000040; 000000000013.380000;000000000000000100;10:11:40.214;1;2019-01-02;000086597182855;000000000400271;1;2019-01-02;000086597151578;000000000400272;2;0;00000058;00000174
2019-01-02;AALR3                                             ;0000000030; 000000000013.380000;000000000000000100;10:11:40.214;1;2019-01-02;000086597182855;000000000400269;1;2019-01-02;000086597151189;000000000400270;2;0;00000058;00000308

im reading it with:

```
    pd.read_csv('//path_to_file', sep=';')
```

I want to name the columns like this.

```
    df.columns = ['Session Date','Instrument Symbol','Trade Number','Trade Price','Traded Quantity',
          'Trade Time','Trade Indicator','Buy Order Date','Sequential Buy Order Number',
          'Secondary Order ID - Buy Order','Aggressor Buy Order Indicator','Sell Order Date',
         'Sequential Sell Order Number','Secondary Order ID - Sell Order','Aggressor Sell Order Indicator',
          'Cross Trade Indicator','Buy Member','Sell Member']
```

UPDATE:

the solutions were effective, thank you very much.

[I is almost the way i want it. Is there a way to make the duplicate indexes a MultiIndex as well? I managed to make the dates, but not the symbol. Thanks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JAcFM.png)

Comment: How is the data being read into a dataframe (e.g. csv), and can you provide a sample of the original data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are seeing is a `MultiIndex Dataframe` , and what you are looking for a `SingleIndex dataframe` ,
 Try

```
df = df.reset_index()
df.columns = ['col1','col2','col3','col4','col5','col6','col7']
```

Comment: This worked, but messed up my row MultiIndex. haha. But one step closer. Thank you!

Comment: @OmarOmeiri If my answer has solved your problem , please marked it as answered  :)

Comment: do you know how can I make the duplicate symbols join into a MultiIndex as well? I posted a picture

Comment: I think you could try , pandas.merge(dataframe1 , dataframe2 , on="SYMBOL")

Answer (score 0):

Make a try with this-

```
your_df = pd.DataFrame(df.column1.str.split(' ',1).tolist(), columns = ['col1','col2','col3','col4','col5','col6','col7'])
print(your_df)
```

Comment: I get this error:  AssertionError: 18 columns passed, passed data had 1 columns